# How to adjust ExtJS window width according to its content?

Tags: javascript, extjs, window, size

I am using ExtJs.

Is there any way to adjust the width of the `Ext.Window` according to its items?

Height is automatically adjusted to 'auto' but `width:'auto'` expands it to full browser window.

```
 var childPnl1 = { // 1
     frame: true,
     width: 350,
     height: 50,
     html: 'My First Child Panel',
     title: 'First children are fun'
 }
 var childPnl2 = { // 2
     width: 150,
     html: 'Second child',
     title: 'Second children have all the fun!'
 }
 new Ext.Window({
     renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
     items: [
         childPnl1,
         childPnl2,
         {
             title: '3rd',
             width: 400, //Maximum
             height: '150',
             frame: true
         }
     ]
 });
```

Now I need a way so that the window adjusts its width to 400.

One way can be to iterate all the `panels` and then get the right most edge, but I want to avoid that.

Comment: Please post some code so we can help you. Also specify version of ExtJs you're using

Answer (score -1):

Ofcourse it will expand to full browser window, why don't you use common variable for your 
**item-width** and **window-width**? Also, it will give you guarantee that your window size neither be large or small than your item-width. Sometimes in different cases, autoWidth behaves different. So it is preferable to use manual width.

Comment: Do you mean to have a constant window width? I want it to adjust its width automatically based on the content inside it.